# How to make a legend for vertex color attributes when colours are defined within the plot argument? (R)

Tags: r, legend, igraph

I don't know how to make a reproducible example out of this. The only important thing is that I would like to make make a legend of the vertex.color argument such that the colours I am using to represent "motherinst" are shown in the legend.

```
plot(g, vertex.size = (V(g)$poly_area*1.25), arrow.size = 0.5, arrow.width = 0.1, vertex.label = V(g)$poly_area, vertex.color = color[as.numeric(as.factor(vertex_attr(g, "motherinst")))], curved = TRUE)
```

I tried adding colours to the graph object directly but that won't seem to work for me either.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the function `legend`.

First make a reproducible graph:

```
require(igraph)
g <- graph_from_atlas(523)
```

I need to know the number of vertices, let's call it `n`

```
n <- length(V(g))
```

Then I create an arbitrary factor that describes a certain property of each node, and assign a color to each node according to this factor. I did not really know what the `poly_area` property was, so I just got creative...

```
f <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:2], length = n))
V(g)$poly_area <- V(g) ** 2
vcols <- c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4")[f]
```

The call to the plottting function is the same (only simplified a little bit for clarity)...

```
plot(g, vertex.size = (V(g)$poly_area + 10), vertex.label = V(g)$poly_area, vertex.color = vcols)
```

... and a legend can be added with `legend`

```
legend("topleft", legend = levels(f), pch = 16, col = vcols, bty = "n")
```

And here is the result !

[image: Graph with legend]

Comment: The colours between my legend and plot are still not matching :/

Comment: I'm sorry about that, can you be specific? Maybe give us a reproducible example?